# Rails 4 - How would I automatically detect a user's location and display it on the web app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, geoip

I currently have a working app and I would like to have Rails detect a visitor's location by the IP address and display the city and state on the homepage of my website. For example, it would display "Hello {Name} from City, State".

Visitors do not have to enter anything. I'm aware of things like GeoIP and Geocode. As far as I know about them, they are used to search for locations from IP or vice versa but they require manually inputting the info.

I need it to do it automatically as soon as the user visits my homepage. I have a Post Controller and a home page, and I just want to add some code to my home page's HAML to display the info. I plan to categorize user's posts based on location, which will be automatically filled in (I currently have a location field that user's must enter manually). If you can show me how to do that too, that would be great.

For a live example of what I'm needing, visit [weather.com](http://weather.com) and you'll see your city (and the weather) on the homepage.

Additional info: I'm fairly new to Rails 4 (started 2 weeks ago) so please show me the simplest way and point me to video resources if possible.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails ?

Comment: Please check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686322/get-user-city-location-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: I'm choosing to close this as too broad. Any potential solution requires a bit more thought than "I just want to add some code to my home page's HAML to display the info".

Comment: Geokit wouldn't work for what I'm needing. It requires manual IP input.

Comment: @max I completely disagree. I'm asking for a very specific request and resources to help me implement it since I'm new. Just because what I want to do is simple (display the info on the home page) doesn't mean it's "broad".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add to the gemfile

```
gem 'geocoder'
```

run `bundle install` and restart your server

Put `<%= request.location.city %>` in the view you want the city name to appear in.

Comment: Will this work on localhost or does the website need to be live? How would I test it if my site's currently on the local machine?

Comment: Yeh, sorry should've mentioned doesn't work locally, since there's no valid ip. If you want to manipulate things in the controller you can, but it's not necessary. For example, you could have `@city = request.location.city` in controller and do a bunch of stuff and then render `<%= @city %>` in the view.

Comment: @Laser ,i did the same but not fetching location, no value is getting there

Comment: @Laser i added gem, installed it and i added <%= request.location.city %> in my view page. it displays as empty. also running in live server. what is wrong with me?

Comment: So locally it should be empty, but if it's happening in deployment it's quite possibly not you, but the default geocoder's service used, freegeoip. See https://github.com/fiorix/freegeoip/issues/159#issuecomment-189754228

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of services that provide RESTful JSON APIs which will give you location data based on the IP address, for example: http://www.telize.com/

All you need to do is in your controller, catch the source of the HTTP request (`Rack::Request`) via `request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']` and feed to the Geo API.

Answer (score 0):

One more solution is to use ruby gem for Yandex locator (https://tech.yandex.ru/locator/). Yandex locator is a service that finds mobile devices in a region delineated by a circle. The service returns longitude, latitude and precision. https://github.com/sergey-chechaev/yandex_locator

```
client = YandexLocator::Client.new(api_key: 'api key', version: '1.0')
result = client.lookup(ip: { address_v4: '178.247.233.3' })
result.position
# => {"altitude"=>0.0, "altitude_precision"=>30.0, "latitude"=>41.00892639160156, "longitude"=>28.96711158752441, "precision"=>100000.0, "type"=>"ip"}
```